# Linux - Create sub-directories from file names in current directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have a list of files in a directory like below.

```
/file1 - filename1.txt
/file2 - filename2a.txt
/file2 - filename2b.txt
/file3 - filename3.txt
/file4 - filename4.txt
/file5 - filename5.txt
```

I am trying to create a script that will parse the files in the specified or working directory, to create folders from the filenames before the dash, if they dont already exist and ignore that file if they do. Then the script will move that filename in the newly created sub-directory.

For example, the list will eventually look like the below.

```
/file1/file1 - filename1.txt
/file2/file2 - filename2a.txt
/file2/file2 - filename2b.txt
/file3/file3 - filename3.txt
/file4/file4 - filename4.txt
/file5/file5 - filename5.txt
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can try with `cut` command to get the directory name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in filename*
do
   d=$( echo $f | sed 's/filename\([0-9]*\).*/file\1/')
   [ -d $d ] || mkdir $d
   mv $f $d
   echo "$f moved to $d"
done
```

Comment: Hi - all files are initially in the same directory. I want to move them into individual directories.

Comment: If you have filename2a.txt and filename2b.txt, do they get concatenated into one file `file2/file2` ?

Comment: No, both files will get put into the same file2 folder. Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: No probs. The solution now places filename1.txt --> file1/filename1.txt. Is this correct?

Comment: So close. However it's treating 'file1 - filename1.txt' as separate files. It fails saying that it cannot move file1 to file1.

mv: cannot move `file1' to a subdirectory of itself, `file1/file1'